# How to get() a widget's IntVariable value from the widget?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to get the value of a `Tkinter.Checkbutton`'s variable using `.get()`, but I get an error.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class myApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()
        self.var = tk.IntVar()
        self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, variable=self.var)
        self.cb.bind('<Button-1>', self.useValue)
        print self.var.get() # works
        print self.cb.get() # does not work
        print self.cb.cget('variable') # prints something like PYNUMVAR1 
        print self.cb.cget('variable').get() # error I mention below
        print self.cb.var.get() # error
        print self.cb.val.get() # error

    def useValue(self, event):
        print event.widget.cget('variable').get()) # why not?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runit = myApp(None)
    runit.mainloop()
```

I tried plenty of combinations of everything I've seen all over stackoverflow and other tutorial sites. The error I  get is:

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It should be an `IntVar`, not a `_tkinter.Tcl_Obj` object, which doesn't have a `get` attribute, when I try, it raises an attribute error on `self.var` like this:

```
print self.var.crumpet()
```

The console lets me know that it is also that type of object. (It did this on my first experiment, but I cannot get it to recreate this error message on the `IntVar` instance in the example code above, so I think this might be wrong.)

I know I can just use `get()` on `self.var`, but if I'm passing the widget to a callback function via the event parameter, I would like to be able to get the value of it.

How can I get the value of the `Checkbutton` without having to do anything with the variable? Should I avoid assigning it a variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> print event.widget.cget('variable').get()) # why not?

It's simply a limitation of tkinter. Conceptually it *should* work, and you can do the equivalent in tcl/tk, but it won't work in tkinter.

In other words, it's a bug, either in the design of tkinter or it's implementation, I'm not sure which.

> How the hell can I get the value of the Checkbutton without having to do anything with the variable? Should I avoid assigning it a variable?

A simple but effective solution is to attach a reference to the widget:

```
class myApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.cb.var = self.var
        ...
    def useValue(self, event):
        print event.widget.var.get()
```

Another solution is the under-documented `getvar` method which takes a tcl variable name as an argument and returns the value.

For example:

```
def useValue(self, event):
    widget = event.widget
    varname = str(widget.cget("variable"))
    print widget.getvar(varname)
```

---

Note: binding to `<Button-1>` means your callback will be called *before* the checkbutton is set or unset. It will always show the previous value. Either bind to `<ButtonRelease-1>`, or put a trace on the variable. The latter is preferable since a binding on `<ButtonRelease-1>` won't fire if the user changes the checkbutton via the keyboard.

Comment: Ended up just giving my cb a cb.var property that I set to the checkbox it is in my long list of checkboxes. I wanted something that easily increases in number. You got me on the right track though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The state of `CheckButton` is indicated in `self.var`, CheckButton object doesn't have any get attribute.

```
        print self.var.get() # Value of CheckButton state
        print self.cb.get() # Checkbutton doesn't have any attribute .get()
        print self.cb.cget('variable') # prints name value stored in tkinter
        print self.cb.cget('variable').get() # self.cb.cget('variable') doesn't have .get attribute
        print self.cb.var.get() # self.cb (checkButton) doesn't have any var attribute
        print self.cb.val.get() # self.cb.val was not declared before
```

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that `Checkbutton` has no `value` option. It has `onvalue` and `offvalue` options which you don't set either. Below code sets `onvalue` of a `Checkbutton` and then displays its `onvalue` and `offvalue` on labels:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, onvalue=32)
on = tk.Label(root, text=cb['onvalue'])
off = tk.Label(root, text=cb['offvalue'])

cb.pack()
on.pack()
off.pack()

root.mainloop()
```